# Angular Material2 - Programmatically setting color

Tags: css, angular, material-design

I am looking for a way to change "accent" color in the theme at runtime inside my component. For example in the constructor.

I have been looking all over for this without luck. All the answers i have found is telling me how to pre-define a theme document that will define the colors for "primary", "accent", "warn".

My application fetches the colors (such as "#FFFFFF") via AJAX on load, and needs to apply them to "primary" or "accent" during runtime.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Css variables are not a thing yet, so I don't think it's possible. See https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#future-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to add css manipulate your container with a viewchild and add internal css.

```js
@ViewChild ('yourcontainer') container: ElementRef;

private yourColorGetted: string = '#FFFFFF';
private yourBackgroundColorGetted: string = '#FFFFFF';

this.container.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML ('beforeend', `<style>
     .candy-carousel {
            background-color: ${this.yourBackgroundColorGetted},
            color: ${this.yourColorGetted}
     }
     </style> `);
```

```html
<div id="yourcontainer"> </ div>
```